# Postion of the option selected in a Select - Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

How do I get the position of the `option` that I have selected. I should work like the `index` of a table:

**In a table**:

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars;let i = index" (click)="showTabs(i)">
   <td>{{i+1}}</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to get that but working for a `select`

**What I have tried for a select**

```
<select (change)="getPos(i);" required>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars;let i = index">whatever</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean saying position ?

Comment: If i click on the option 3, to get a 3

Comment: What do you want to get instead?

Comment: What actually you get with your code example ?

Comment: My work example is for a table. I want to have the same for a select

Comment: Have you tried anything with select ?

Comment: What have you tried? Why would it be different for select?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the issue is using `HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex` property like:

```
(change)="index = $event.target.selectedIndex"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a select, you can give a "value" to option. You can choose "value=index", then in $event.target.value you have "index"

```
<select (change)="getValue($event);" required>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars;let i = index" [value]="i">{{car}}</option>
</select>
getValue(event:any)
{
  let index:number=+event.target.value; //event.target.value is a string
  console.log(event.target.value,index);
}
```

Or you can choose get a value and use findIndex

```
<select (change)="getValue($event);" required>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars;let i = index" [value]="car.id">{{car}}</option>
</select>
getValue(event:event)
{
  //if your cars if some like [{id:1,name:"lamborggini"},{id:2,name="porche"}..]
  let index:number=cars.findIndex(c=>c.id==event.target.value;
  console.log(event.target.value,index);
}
```